# How to use a list of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, object, windows-forms-designer

i have created some code in which there is a list of objects. i have created a method that i want to use on one of the objects in the list. how do i find that object in the list and use the method on that specific object? this is the code:

```
LstInvoice.Add(new Invoice (InvNumberIn, InvTotalIn, PaidIn, DateIn, SuppNameIn ));
```

i want to use the method below on one of the objects in  the list and choose the object by using the InvoiceNumber Value:

```
public void MakePayment(string invoicenumberIn, double amount)
    {
        
        CurrentInvoiceTotal = InvoiceTotal - amount;
    }
```

if it is unclear, this is an invoice management program and the current feature i am coding is to be able to make a payment on an invoice which is in the list of invoices.

Comment: **NEVER** use `double` or `float` to represent monetary amounts: they're IEEE-754 _approximate types_ which are completely inappropriate for representing money values because they are _imprecise_ types. Instead either use `Decimal` (which is precise) or integer-cents.

Comment: What is the exact type of `LstInvoice`?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use LINQ to find an item in the list by its invoice number. Something like this:

```
public void MakePayment(string invoicenumberIn, double amount)
{
    Invoice invoice = LstInvoice.FirstOrDefault(i => i.InvNumber == invoicenumberIn);
    if (invoice != null)
        invoice.CurrentInvoiceTotal = invoice.InvoiceTotal - amount;
}
```

Replace `InvNumber` with whatever the name of the property that represents the number in the `Invoice` class is.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` has `O(n)` time - and I get the feeling that `MakePayment` would be called repetitively., so I suggest that `LstInvoice` (_ugh_, Hungarian...) should use a hash-map of some kind for `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: Yes, but how is this related to the question being asked or this answer?

Comment: Because your code uses `FirstOrDefault` - and **I'm suggesting an improvement** where you could memoize the collection to a map-type for significantly improved lookup time.